# Python, gensim, doc2vec. Classify phrases by themes

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I have a number of known themes and a dataset with phrases on these themes. 
As a result I need get the theme of a phrase which is not in the dataset.
I train gensim doc2vec model on this dataset using only phrases. Here TaggedDocument is a list of words of a phrase.

```
train_data = list(create_tagged_document(data))
#> [TaggedDocument(words=['anarchism', 'originated', ... 'social', 'or', 'emotional'], tags=[0])]
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=1000)
model.build_vocab(train_data)
model.train(train_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

Then I find the closest phrases to a new phrase.

```
test_vec = model.infer_vector(['lorem', 'ipsum', 'new', 'phrase', 'words'])
similars = model.docvecs.most_similar([test_vec], topn=len(model.docvecs))
```

After that I check the themes of the closest phrases (based on cosine similarity probably) and if the closest phrases are close enough then decide that new phrase has the same theme as the closest.
Does this approach make sense? And did doc2vec model used correctly?

Comment: What are you supplying as the `tags` for each text? How many texts do you have, of how long on average and how many unique words? And most importantly: when you tried it, did your results make sense for your purposes?

Comment: @gojomo I started with tags as sequence '0', '1', '2'. Now tag is id of a phrase in database. Basically the same: unique int as string. Dataset is filling. Now I have 2000 phrases by 2 themes. It will be 20k phrases by 20 themes. Each phrase is from 4 to approx 50 words. Now when I have 2k phrases by 2 themes the result is not bad, most similar phrases have the same theme as new phrase.

Comment: If it's working OK, that's as close to "used correctly" as most can hope to achieve! That's a very-small dataset, compared to published `Doc2Vec` results, but the smaller vector-size & larger-iterations can sometimes eke out usefulness from tiny datasets. You approach of looking at the top-n most-similar items, & using their themes (labels) as the prediction for your new text is approximating the behavior of a "KNN classifier". You could try using other off-the-shelf classifiers, formally, with the doc-vectors as features & the known-labels as training data, & perhaps do even better.